# Gridline only on 0 in column range

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highcharts column range and would like to have the gridline only on 0. Is it possible?

```
    yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: '#197F07',
        gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        text: '%'
         }
      },
```

Comment: If the provided answer doesn't help you, can you show us what exactly you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can have this result by using `yAxis.plotLine` [API doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines)

```
yAxis: {
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  plotLines: [{
    color: '#AAAAAA',
    width: 1,
    value: 0
  }]
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4sx15bmy/)

Comment: @AndrewGlushchenko, If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.